# List only temporary aliases in bash

Tags: bash, alias

I know that to list all aliases in a given bash session with `alias -p`. Is there a way to get a list of all the temporary aliases in a given bash session, i.e. all aliases that aren't in my bash profile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's not that simple. There is no concept of "temporary" aliases in bash, and for bash any command executed by sourcing .bashrc is the same as any you type into the command line. Moreover the bash profile files could define some aliases only under some circumstances.

You could save into a variable (or file) the aliases which are set after the bash profile files are executed and then, when you need it, check the difference between such variable and the aliases currently set:

```
$ BASE_ALIAS="$(alias | sort)"
$ alias tmp_alias=""
$ unalias ls
$ diff <( echo "$BASE_ALIAS" ) <( alias | sort )
3d2
< alias ls='ls --color=auto'
5a5
> alias tmp_alias=''
```

`diff` shows that an alias `ls` has been removed and an alias `tmp_alias` has been added since the declaration of `BASE_ALIAS`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with the following:

```
comm -2 -3 --nocheck-order <(alias -p) <(bash -l -c 'alias -p')
```

This works by comparing the current list of aliases with the aliases present in a brand new shell.
The `comm` utility is used to show only lines that are present in the first command `<(alias -p)`. The `--nocheck-order` is necessary to keep it from complaining that the alias list isnt in order, even though it really is...

Comment: The aliases defined by the bash profile files for a brand new shell could be different from the ones defined by those same files for the current shell (i.e. `[[ $(( $RANDOM % 2 )) == 0 ]] && alias ...`). Nice hint about using `comm` though!

Comment: @peoro nobody is going to do that though. Seriously, you start a shell from the exact same TTY as the original shell, the environment is the same, there is no reason why aliases would be different.